# R Shiny conditional dateInput for every checkboxGroupInput selected

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I am creating an app that allows the user to multi-select a list of projects. For each project selected, I would like to have a dateInput field  to appear beside the project name (i.e. a/b/c).

Currently, I can display dateInput field for any one of the projects, but not multiple (shown below)

[image: One dateInput field for one selected project]

Once multiple dateInputs display beside project list as shown below: I wonder how the dateInput fields can line up nicely because they seem to take up more space than the checkbox list, like this:

[image]

```
ui <-  dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = ""
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Projects", tabName = "tab1")
    ) 
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
              fluidRow(h2("Projects"), 
                column(6,
                       checkboxGroupInput("Projects", "",
                                          c("a", "b", "c")
                       )
                ),
                column(4,
                       conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Projects == 'a' || 
                                        input.Projects == 'b' || input.Projects 
                                        == 'c'", dateInput("proj_date", ""))
                       )
                )
              )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I understand I need to put in javascript in the conditionalPanel's condition argument. Please advise how I should correct the code and have one or more dateInput fields displayed for any and all selected projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `uiOutput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <-  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Projects", tabName = "tab1")
        ) 
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
                    fluidRow(h2("Projects"), 
                             column(6, checkboxGroupInput("Projects", "", c("a", "b", "c"))),
                             column(4, uiOutput('dates'))))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$dates <- renderUI({
        lapply(input$Projects, function(project) {
            div(dateInput(paste0("proj_date_",project), paste("Project", project, "date")))
        })
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Would it be much work to align them with the project position, i.e. third dateInput lining up with third checkbox, instead of with the first checkbox if that is the only selected project? Given that I already managed to make the dateInput boxes shorter. Thank you kindly.

Comment: I suggest do `fluidRow` for each project with `checkBoxInput` instead of `checkboxGroupInput`. And then show dateInput if checkbox is checked.